# Нужна помощь по скачиванию контента с инстаграм

Tags: python, aiogram, instagram

Всем привет. Хочу написать бота, который скачивает контент(видео, фото, рилс итп) с инстаграма. Однако, я не знаю как это сделать. Я хотел через библиотеку instaloader, но не сработало, нашел АПИ, вроде работал, но часто выдавал ошибки, да и ограничение на него было. Попробовал через пост запрос к сайтам типа instagram loader, но тоже как то не получилось. Выдавал 403. Может быть вы писали подобное и знаете как решить эту проблему или вы знаете бесплатный АПИ, без лимита, с помощью которого это все можно легко реализовать?

Comment: может быть для вашей задачи подойдет selenium
https://www.selenium.dev/